# spring data @ManyToOne @MapsId

Tags: spring-data-jpa, mapping

can some one help me to map this 3 entities correctly, because i have tried many solution but not working.
i have this 3 entities :
Product,Item and Pack that should be mapped like this:

### Product entity

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentProduct", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private List<Pack> packListParent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="childProduct", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private List<Pack> packListChild;
 }
```

### Pack entity

```
public class Pack implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected PackPK PackPK;

    @MapsId("itemId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "item_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Item item;

    @MapsId("parentProductId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product parentProduct;

    @MapsId("childProductId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product childProduct;           
}

@Embeddable
public class PackPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long parentProductId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private Long itemId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "child_product_id")
    private Long childProductId;
}
```

### Item entity

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private List<Pack> PackList;
}
```

this mapping work in eclipselink but when i have migrated to spring data jpa with eclipselink i have this warning when i launch the server application.

This is the error message :

```
WARN  - [AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] 
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'produitService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'PackService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'PackService': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected id attribute type [class com.project.jpa.domain.PackPK] 
on the existing id attribute [SingularAttributeImpl[EntityTypeImpl@1851998201:Item 
[ javaType: class com.project.jpa.domain.Item descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.project.jpa.domain.Item --> [DatabaseTable(item)]), mappings: 47],
org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[item]]] on the identifiable type [EntityTypeImpl@1341697553:Pack [ javaType: class com.project.jpa.domain.Pack descriptor: 
RelationalDescriptor(com.project.jpa.domain.Pack --> [DatabaseTable(pack_svod_content)]), mappings: 6]] but found attribute type [class com.project.jpa.domain.Item].
```

Comment: Remove  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Comment: i already tried this but not working

Comment: IMHO in the OneToMany mapping PackList there is a mappedBy="item" missing

Comment: Did you find the answer?? Still EclipseLink 2.7.7 has that problem..